# Accessing FB Business Manager API

Tags: r, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, httr

I am trying to access FB Business Manager Marketing API to get data on my Ad Set data.

The way I went about accessing this is by first creating an app through here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Should I use something else like `Rfacebook`? This is how I did it below:

I retrieved my App Id and App Secret.

From here, I made a call to the API by doing this which worked:

```
appKey<- 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
appSecret<- 'YYYYYYYYY'

response = POST(
  'https://accounts.facebook.com/api/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(appKey, appSecret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
)

token = content(response)$access_token

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', token)
```

From here, I want to call my account based on the fields provided here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.11

My attempt to do this is as follows:

```
accountname<-'1234567'

account_url <- "https://api.facebook.com/v2.11/account_name/1234567"
Account <- GET(account_url, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
```

When I run Account, I get this output:

```
Response [https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser]
  Date: 2018-01-05 21:39
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 309 kB
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="default" 
id="meta_referrer" /><script>window._cstart=+new Date();</script>...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yl/l/0,cross/Ms7B4ehALEW.css" 
data-bootloader-hash...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y3/l/0,cross/684seag7DTg.css" 
data-bootloader-hash...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yK/l/0,cross/g8YvVQ4GaAa.css" 
data-bootloader-hash...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yY/l/0,cross/423Tvkgz0LR.css" 
data-bootloader-hash...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y1/l/0,cross/leqp1EQMeCH.css" 
data-bootloader-hash...
<script src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yC/r/3-Z0DsUATk-.js" 
data-bootloader-hash="+/Mwn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>requireLazy(["ix"],function(ix){ix.add({"125923":
{"sprited":true,"spriteCssClass":"sx_4ccccf","spriteMapCssClass":"sp_lM6-
CJgzF...
...
```

I then try and convert it from json but get an error.

Do you think this is the best way to access FB Business Manager's API for Marketing or should I go a different route? I already tried this method but it didn't work for me: https://github.com/daroczig/fbRads

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the `fbRads` package and have been using it for 2 years in prod. Not sure what you mean by "it didn't work", but I'd highly suggest relying on an SDK (eg the `fbRads` package) instead of writing your own functions to interact with the bare API to save you quite a lot of time while figuring out its caveats, eg handling temp errors etc

Comment: @daroczig just sent you a message on your website for some assistance. Let me know if interested. Also, would you prefer if I post a new question going through the error when using your package `fbRads`? Thanks